# Strange issue with System.out.println() and the Scanner

Tags: java, system, java-7, println

I have a while loop that is always true that asks the user to input a letter. When a letter is inputted it is looked for in a switch statement and then a block of code is executed from the switch statement where more inputs are asked for. It seems like the outputs of the code are being registered as the input of the user in some portions of the code. Here is a brief sample of my code :

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a letter :: ");
    selection = keyboard.nextLine();
    selection = selection.toUpperCase();

    switch (selection) {
    case "A":
        A = null;
        A = new Matrix();
        System.out.println("Default matrix A initialized.");
        break;

    case "C":
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows (rows > 0) :: ");
        rows = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out
                .print("Enter the number of columns (colums > 0) :: ");
        cols = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out
                .print("Enter the initial value for each element :: ");
        initialValue = keyboard.nextInt();

        C = null;
        C = new Matrix(rows, cols, initialValue);
        System.out.println("Matrix C initialized.");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more clear about your problem? At-first glance it seems because of you are using System.out.print() instead of System.out.println()

Comment: What is your expected and actual output?

Comment: Your code give me an error : Cannot switch on a value of type String. Only convertible int values or enum constants are permitted, you should use character ('A', 'B', 'C') instead of ("A", "B", "C")

Comment: Ok so it will output "Enter a letter :: " and I'll type "C". Then I'll fill in the input for the switch case C and I'll get the output :         "Matrix C initialized." and then "Enter a letter :: Enter a letter :: ".

Comment: @IswantoSan, I think OP maybe using Java 7, in that case it works fine.

Comment: @PradeepSimha: Oh sorry, i miss it

Comment: @Jimmy: what happen with your current code ? I think it's work as you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nextInt()` gets the next int, but doesn't read the new line character. In your source you are using `nextInt()` in case "C", you need to include another `nextLine()` to move to next line.

```
case "C":
 ...
 ...
 keyboard.nextLine();
break;
```

Comment: Thanks, I added keyboard.nextLine() after every keyboard.nextInt() and my program now works!